# Error when run TrainCascade.exe

Tags: c++, opencv

I  have one prolem when i try to use traincascade.exe of opencv, i have 20 positive sample and 100 negative sample. perhaps, it few sample but i just want test how to use traincascade.exe of opencv.

I use opencv_createsamples.exe to create vector file with command.

```
D:\Project_Android\Classifier\bin\opencv_createsamples.exe -info positive.txt -vec vector.vec -num 442 -w 24 -h 24 PAUSE
```

It's done, and i have a vector.vec, i have negative.txt with absolute direction too.

But now, when i use traincascade.exe with command

```
D:\Project_Android\Classifier\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data HaarTraining -vec vector.vec -bg negative.txt -npos 10 -nneg 10 -numStages 3 -nsplits 2 -nonsym -minhitrate 0.95 -maxfalsealarm 0.4 -mem 1024 -mode ALL -w 24 -h 24 PAUSE
```

it say error like a below picture.

[image]

So i decide replace opencv_traincascade.exe to opencv_haartraining.exe with command

```
D:\Project_Android\Classifier\bin\opencv_haartraining.exe -data HaarTraining -vec vector.vec -bg negative.txt -npos 10 -nneg 10 -numStages 3 -nsplits 2 -nonsym -minhitrate 0.95 -maxfalsealarm 0.4 -mem 1024 -mode ALL -w 24 -h 24 PAUSE
```

Now it run a few minute.

after it finish, i just see 8 folder(0,1,2,...) in HaarTraining folder, i tried to find xml file but no see it, it seem to be it not generate xml file
[image]

So, Please tell me what problem with it, i don't know why does it say error with opencv_traincascade.exe and run with opencv_haartraining.exe but not generate xml file. I am sure positive.txt and negative.txt have right absolute direction to image.

So many thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `opencv_haartraining.exe`. It is now deprecated.

To answer your question, your parameters should be the following:

```
opencv_traincascade.exe -data HaarTraining -vec vector.vec -bg negative.txt -numPos 10 -numNeg 10 -numStages 3 -minHitRate 0.95 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.4 -mode ALL -w 24 -h 24
```

As for your `-mem 1024`, `-nsplits 2`, and `-nonsym` flags, they aren't actual parameters used by `opencv_traincascade.exe`. The closest thing your `-mem` flag is probably either `-precalcValBufSize` and `-precalcIdxBufSize`.

For a more comprehensive list of arguments, you can check out [the official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html#cascade-training).